# Method for initial guess of standard deviation of 2d gaussian/gabor?

Tags: curve-fitting, gaussian, standard-deviation, gabor-filter

I'm working on curve fitting software in Matlab. So far it's going pretty well but I need a method of inputting an initial guess for my curve fitting software. I'm given a selection of points, but I need to find an initial guess of the SDx and SDy but I don't know how to do this. Is there anywhere I can learn a good approach to this? Thank you so much!

My data is a 32x32 matrix that looks something like the following: 
     -0.0027   -0.0034   -0.0034    0.0003    0.0018    0.0028    0.0058    0.0057    0.0008   -0.0053
   -0.0023   -0.0008   -0.0007    0.0005    0.0015    0.0033    0.0062    0.0054    0.0029   -0.0029
   -0.0018    0.0004    0.0014    0.0009    0.0006    0.0024    0.0047    0.0045    0.0041    0.0009
   -0.0034   -0.0020    0.0022    0.0022   -0.0007    0.0003    0.0012    0.0024    0.0022    0.0015
   -0.0053   -0.0042   -0.0004    0.0010   -0.0014   -0.0020   -0.0021   -0.0003    0.0002   -0.0014
   -0.0070   -0.0034   -0.0008    0.0000    0.0004    0.0032    0.0011    0.0019    0.0026    0.0006
   -0.0054   -0.0016    0.0005    0.0012    0.0000    0.0045    0.0033    0.0035    0.0039    0.0013
   -0.0050   -0.0015   -0.0009    0.0001    0.0001    0.0013   -0.0022   -0.0010    0.0012   -0.0024
   -0.0044   -0.0028   -0.0019    0.0016    0.0026   -0.0005   -0.0057   -0.0057   -0.0042   -0.0057
   -0.0037   -0.0022   -0.0024    0.0003    0.0036    0.0002   -0.0045   -0.0055   -0.0039   -0.0032
   -0.0045   -0.0012   -0.0016   -0.0016    0.0000    0.0003   -0.0018   -0.0014    0.0025   -0.0015
   -0.0047   -0.0028   -0.0028   -0.0021   -0.0041   -0.0025   -0.0008    0.0011    0.0020   -0.0029
   -0.0028   -0.0020   -0.0024   -0.0024   -0.0044   -0.0060   -0.0032    0.0009    0.0018   -0.0008
   -0.0005   -0.0017    0.0007    0.0025   -0.0020   -0.0030   -0.0010   -0.0011   -0.0004    0.0014
   -0.0011   -0.0006   -0.0001    0.0003   -0.0002    0.0012    0.0033    0.0010   -0.0025   -0.0001
   -0.0032   -0.0008    0.0001   -0.0039   -0.0022    0.0003    0.0016    0.0016   -0.0009   -0.0008
   -0.0060   -0.0019   -0.0005   -0.0033   -0.0039   -0.0032   -0.0018   -0.0004   -0.0012   -0.0004
   -0.0077   -0.0049   -0.0039   -0.0039   -0.0049   -0.0044   -0.0039   -0.0047   -0.0034   -0.0031
   -0.0054   -0.0026   -0.0030   -0.0046   -0.0071   -0.0048   -0.0028   -0.0051   -0.0046   -0.0042
   -0.0049    0.0002    0.0009   -0.0017   -0.0041   -0.0031   -0.0018   -0.0024   -0.0029   -0.0015
   -0.0032   -0.0007    0.0021    0.0012   -0.0006   -0.0013   -0.0008

Comment: Why not calculate the value from the points you have?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate a standard deviation in the x and the y direction. I added sample data above.